# Awk Remove lines if one column matches another column, and keep line if max value from another column

Tags: awk

I have a file of ~8,000 lines.  I am trying to remove the lines where when the 5th column  matches (in this case **ga2016mldlzd)**, but keep only the line with the max value in the 6th column.  For example, if given this:

```
-25.559,129.8529,6674.560547,2.0,ga2016mldlzd,6
-25.5596,129.8565,6902.750651,2.0,ga2016mldlzd,7
-25.5450,129.830,969.8079427,2.0,ga2016mldlzd,8
-25.5450,129.834,57.04752604,2.0,ga2016mldlzd,9
-25.57067,129.856,7929.60612,2.0,ga2016mldlzd,10
```

remove all lines except the final line with 10 as the max value, to get this.  I'm stumped as to how this could be done either in awk or sed?

```
-25.57067,129.856,7929.60612,2.0,ga2016mldlzd,10
```

If tried this:

```
awk -F, '!a[$5]++'
```

but I want to keep last column e.g., the column with '10', rather than the column with '6'.  Thanks

Comment: You should have included some lines where the 5th column DOESN'T equal "ga2016mldlzd" so we have something to test a potential solution against for that part of your requirement. Where is the "if one column matches another column" requirement from your subject line demonstrated in your example? I don't see any rows where the values in 2 columns are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep track of the max and line associated with that max and print at the end:

```
awk -F, '
    {
        if ($6>max[$5]) {
            max[$5]=$6
            tl[$5]=$0
            }
    }
END{
    for (l in tl) print tl[l]
}' file
```

Prints:

```
-25.57067,129.856,7929.60612,2.0,ga2016mldlzd,10
```

The order of the file will be lost; ie, the groups may be reordered compared to the original file.

---

---

If you are dealing with a file with many different keys for `$5` and not all of them could fit in memory, you could sort into blocks grouped by the fifth field and then by the numeric value of the sixth. Then have `awk` print the last line every time the fifth field changes. Since it is sorted, that will be the max:

```
sort -t , -k 5,5 -k 6n file |  
awk -F, '
    FNR==1{lf=$5;ll=$0} 
    lf!=$5{print ll}
    {ll=$0; lf=$5}
    END{print $0}' 

# same print out
```

The second there will be way slower but way less memory for a large number of `$5` uniq values.

Comment: second one would be effective with huge data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain original order of lines then use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {if ($6 > max[$5]) max[$5] = $6; next} $5 in max && max[$5] == $6' file file

-25.57067,129.856,7929.60612,2.0,ga2016mldlzd,10
```

If you want to filter for `ga2016mldlzd` while maintaining original order of lines then use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F, '
NR==FNR {
   if ($5 == "ga2016mldlzd" && $6 > max[$5]) {
      max[$5] = $6
      n = FNR
   }
   next
}
FNR == n' file file

-25.57067,129.856,7929.60612,2.0,ga2016mldlzd,10
```